# Differentiate between Adding and Editing a CoreData Item (Notes)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I am successfully creating and saving a new CoreData item (in my App's case, Notes) using the following code:

```
let note = CoreDataHelper.newNote()
            note.noteTitle = noteTitleTextField.text ?? ""
            note.noteContent = noteContentTextView.text ?? ""
            note.noteDate = Date() as NSDate
            CoreDataHelper.saveNote()
```

But what happens is this:

The App creates a new Note every time I edit an existing one.

What can I do to differentiate between:

- Adding a new Note; and
- Editing an existing Note?

Here are what I have:

A. In the first View Controller (table showing a list of saved Notes), I have a "Prepare for Segue" function:

- Adding a new Note (Segue = "addNote"); and
- Displaying existing Note (Segue = "displayNote")

On the "displayNote" segue, I have this code:

```
if identifier == "displayNote" {

                let noteDetailViewController = segue.destination as! DisplayNoteViewController

                if let selectedNoteCell = sender as? ListNotesTableViewCell {
                    let indexPath = notesTableView.indexPath(for: selectedNoteCell)!
                    let selectedNote = notes[indexPath.row]
                    noteDetailViewController.note = selectedNote
```

I have no problem displaying the selected Note(s).

B. On the "DisplayNoteViewController" itself (where the user can do the viewing and editing of notes), I have the following "Prepare for Segue" function:

```
if identifier == "saveNote" {

            // if note exists, function should update title and content only; NOT create a new note

            let note = CoreDataHelper.newNote()
            note.noteTitle = noteTitleTextField.text ?? ""
            note.noteContent = noteContentTextView.text ?? ""
            note.noteDate = Date() as NSDate
            CoreDataHelper.saveNote()
```

// This code is same as the above.

Comment: You need to track the item which is editing and rewrite only the data,
I think in `saveNote()` method you are save always new entry into CodeData.
Instead of this you need to write one method which will modify the data.

Comment: @SumeetMourya yes that's what I am trying to figure out how to do... that's actually my question. :)

Comment: You can do one thing, Add one more parameter in your data entity **ID** and on the basis of this **ID** you can keep tracking on which item do you have to display, if you modify data regarding this ID modify your data.

Comment: The app works like the native iPhone Notes app... whatever note the user clicks on the list, it will be displayed and the user can either just read or edit it. What I need to do is to just 'update' the note details if the user modified the contents. What happens on my app is that instead of updating the specific note, it creates a new one... how do I get around this problem?

Comment: Don't create it complicated, for performing editing on already save data, we need one ID/reference with this we can perform some operation.
For that you can define one **parameter**, with you can modified data in coreData.
for checking data is updated you can set a false initially and while save you can check this variable that you need to save **New Entry** or **modify previous data**

Comment: @SumeetMourya can you provide me a sample?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155994/discussion-between-sumeet-mourya-and-pinkblossoms7).

Comment: My question was not yet answered. Chat seemed to be abandoned. Please help.